# React native: error: cannot find symbol after upgrade

Tags: java, android, facebook, reactjs, react-native

Hi after importing my react native project expo and upgrading react, I've been have the following problems.

> C:\Users\user\gramic\android\app\src\main\java\com\shop\MainApplication.java:5:
>   error: cannot find symbol import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
>                            ^   symbol:   class ReactApplication   location: package com.facebook.react
>   C:\Users\user\gramic\android\app\src\main\java\com\shop\MainApplication.java:13:
>   error: cannot find symbol import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
>                            ^   symbol:   class ReactNativeHost   location: package com.facebook.react
>   C:\Users\user\gramic\android\app\src\main\java\com\shop\MainApplication.java:21:
>   error: cannot find symbol public class MainApplication extends
>   Application implements ReactApplication {
>                                                               ^   symbol: class ReactApplication
>   C:\Users\user\gramic\android\app\src\main\java\com\shop\MainApplication.java:23:
>   error: cannot find symbol   private final ReactNativeHost
>   mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
>                   ^   symbol:   class ReactNativeHost   location: class MainApplication
>   C:\Users\user\gramic\android\app\src\main\java\com\shop\MainApplication.java:40:
>   error: cannot find symbol   public ReactNativeHost
>   getReactNativeHost() {
>            ^   symbol:   class ReactNativeHost   location: class MainApplication
>   C:\Users\user\gramic\android\app\src\main\java\com\shop\MainActivity.java:5:
>   error: MainActivity is not abstract and does not override abstract
>   method getPackages() in ReactActivity public class MainActivity
>   extends ReactActivity {
>          ^ C:\Users\user\gramic\android\app\src\main\java\com\shop\MainApplication.java:23:
>   error: cannot find symbol   private final ReactNativeHost
>   mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
>                                                          ^   symbol:   class ReactNativeHost   location: class MainApplication
>   C:\Users\user\gramic\android\app\src\main\java\com\shop\MainApplication.java:39:
>   error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>   @Override   ^

```
    package com.shop;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.corbt.keepawake.KCKeepAwakePackage;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.github.yamill.orientation.OrientationPackage;
import com.BV.LinearGradient.LinearGradientPackage;
import com.brentvatne.react.ReactVideoPackage;

import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new VectorIconsPackage(),
            new VectorIconsPackage(),
            new KCKeepAwakePackage(),
            new VectorIconsPackage(),
            new OrientationPackage(),
            new LinearGradientPackage(),
            new ReactVideoPackage()

      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

First: install all dependencies using **yarn** or **npm**;

Second: use the code below to link native dependencies on iOS and Android native code;

```
react-native link
```

Third: this error can occur because you RN version is different from Android's build.gradle version. When you create a react-native app probably it create android app like:

```
android/app/build.gradle

implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
```

So, inspect you node_modules folder, look for react-native folder and look for a folder with a number, that numbers are react-native version. For me it's **0.58.3** then update **android/app/build.gradle**:

```
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.58.3"
```

It's All.

Comment: had to add this : `implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.58.4"` matching the version in my package.json

Comment: You can use this information to set build.gradle's react-native version.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you. The issue just came out of the blue for me, then I realized that `react-native` had released a new version `0.59`, so I set it to `0.58.6`.

Answer (score 8):

I also had these errors when trying to upgrade React Native.
I have seen people resolve those by cleaning gradlew cache (`./gradlew clean` in Android project folder) or deleting the whole `.gradle` folder (in Android project folder also).

But that did not work for me. My issue was in the `android/build.gradle` file. I previously had to add a maven repository for another package and had done it that way:

```
maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"

        // The following is NOT the right way
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
```

but it is said in the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html) that every maven repository should be in its own `maven {}` block.

Thus the solution that worked for me was to do that:

```
maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }

maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
```

Hope it will help, and good luck for your react upgrade! ;)

Comment: It's not a good ideia, react-native library and others library are in package.json on a version X so when you download from others source the version can be others different of X.

Comment: @Marcus why isn't it a good idea? I fail to see the link between your comment and my answer as I didn't talk about library versions in it...

Comment: Tried all other suggestions and this was the one that worked for me

Comment: Let me tell you, You SAVED my day!

Answer (score 6):

Happened to me too after detach my react-native project from Expo.

As I answered here:

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120454/cannot-resolve-symbol-reactapplication-reactnativehost/53766604#53766604)

in order to fix the issue I had to:

1. in package.js I changed:

   "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-29.0.0.tar.gz",

   to :

   "react-native": "^0.57.8",
2. delete node_modules file
3. run npm install
4. delete '.gradle' folder from android project and sync project.

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me appeared after I renamed the packages in the app. I used this to rename them:

```
npm install react-native-rename -g
react-native-rename "MyApp" -b com.mycompany.myapp
```

And there were a couple of lines that I needed to update manually:

- android/app/src/main/java/com/winryde/MainActivity.java
- android/app/src/main/java/com/winryde/MainApplication.java
- android/app/src/debug/java/com/winryde/ReactNativeFlipper.java

I just searched for **com.companyname** and changed to the new name.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and all the advice I found didn't help, so I'm dropping this for anyone else having the same issue.

For me it turned out to be a 3rd party package (pushwoosh-react-native-plugin) that compiled/implemented a static version of react-native in it's build.gradle file.

I managed to find it, by

- going to my app/build.gradle
- commented out all my compiles/implementation on dependencies
- added them one by one until i got the same error

As said above:
It turned out to be the pushwoosh build.gradle file that had the following dependency defined:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1'
    ...
}
```

So i went ahead and changed it right on the spot to "+"

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    ...
}
```

**The "+" means:**
the latest available version where each of the leading SEMVER components match the pattern provided

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall react-native-reanimated previous version.
2. cd android
3. ./gradlew clean
4. cd ..
5. install react-native-reanimated@2.12.0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue i reslolve it with this command

```
npx create react app myapp
```